# FLASK - AJAX GET data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, get

I am making a "write anything here" webpage where users can write anything in a textbox then post it and it is visible to everyone. It worked fine till I found out that when any user writes and submits, all the others have to refresh the page so as to get the new data from database. So a solution to this was to call ajax continuously in some intervals. This would check if there are new entries in the table. If yes, then it would render it to the html without refreshing the whole page. Now I am pure ajax noob and after hours of research I am unable to find out how to do it.

**Here is the html code**

```
    <div id="textArea">
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000" method="POST">
          <br>
          <textarea minlength="3" name="comment" placeholder="Enter Text Here.." required></textarea>
          <input id="postButton" type="submit" name="" value="POST">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="show">
      {% for item in data %}
        <div id="auto" class="disPost">{{item[0]}}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Here the textarea is in a form and it submits the text to database via flask server.
Also, all the comments that users wrote are shown in "div.show"

**Now the flask code is like this**

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        post = request.form["comment"]

        myquery = "select p_id from posts order by p_id desc limit 1"
        mycursor.execute(myquery)

        new_p_id = mycursor.fetchone()[0] + 1

        myquery = "select exists(select * from posts where p_des=%s)"
        rec_tup = (post,)
        mycursor.execute(myquery, rec_tup)
        if mycursor.fetchone()[0]==0:
            myquery = "insert into posts values(%s, %s)"
            rec_tup = (new_p_id, post)
            mycursor.execute(myquery, rec_tup)
            mydb.commit()


    mycursor.execute("select distinct p_des from posts order by p_id desc")
    data = mycursor.fetchall()    
    return render_template("homepage.html", data=data)
```

"mydb" is the connector & "mycursor" is the connector's cursor

Now I am stuck somewhere in how to call AJAX function. I am not able to write beyond this ..

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {          
          $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'GET',
            data: //something must be here,

            success: function(data) {

              //here "div" must be added to the "show" class - that is comment of other users

            }
          })

        }, 3000);

      });
```

I know that I have to do something like this but am literally not able to solve it.

I know this is not good question and I must look at tutorials first. But believe me I had it all. I am not able to solve this problem at all.
Thank you for seeing this :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my latest project, you can try it too. But make sure to refresh only div element you want the data show, not all the page.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
            function getData(){
 $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'GET',
            data: //something must be here,

            success: function(data) {

              //here "div" must be added to the "show" class - that is comment of other users

            }
          });
}
    getData();
setInterval(function() {getData()},2000);
          });
```

Comment: I think you are doing the same thing.. coz you're calling getData in setInterval and I am doing the same thing in setInterval.

Comment: Also I need help with the ajax code specifically, that what should I write to retrieve the data from database. Thanks for responding though !